# how to export function so it is accessible with import and require?

Tags: javascript

I want to export a function so it is accessible for testing with mocha and to be used in html

if I export like below, mocha return SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

```
//query.js
export function proses (data)  {
...}
```

if I export it like below, it would return error proses undefined

```
//query.js
function proses (data)  {
...}
module.exports = proses;
```

this is how I imported them on index.js and on test.js

```
//index.js
import { proses } from '../public/static/query.js'
```

and on test.js

```
//test.js
var proses = require('../public/static/query');
```

Comment: You can't do it at the source code level, CommonJS and ESM cannot be combined in the same source code.

Comment: try storing it in a var. I am doing it like : `const proses = function proses() { //stuff }; export default proses;` and then I import it like `import proses from './path/to/file'`. Works for ES6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is best you choose either CommonJs or ESM and stick to that.
For CommonJs:

```
//query.js
function proses (data)  {
...}

module.exports = proses
```

And when importing:

```
const proses = require('../public/static/query');
```